# Restarting all core processes in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, memory, powershell, reboot

Is there any way to restart all **core**/user processes and free-up unused and cached memory thereby simulating a **Reboot** except that it is way **faster** and **easier**.

I know the way to
-Simulate a Reboot to take some effects after some change in settings can be done by [restarting "Explorer" process in Task manager](http://www.wikihow.com/Restart-Windows-Explorer-Without-Rebooting-Computer)

What I need is a way to restart processes without hard-rebooting to free-up some RAM-memory

> On Android smartphones, there's an app called [Fast Reboot](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.greatbytes.fastreboot&hl=en) which does pretty good work.

Are there any softwares or can it be done without any? using powershell/cmd?

Comment: Logging out will restart a lot of processes (not as much as a soft reboot on Android does) and stop some services, but it will clean up a lot of stuff. Have you tried that yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you need is a memory optimiser then there are plenty of them for windows but I personally don't think they make a difference in performance of the system.
Some of them are given below
One : [RAMRush](http://www.fcleaner.com/ramrush.htm)
Two : [Clean Ram](http://download.cnet.com/Clean-Ram/3000-2086_4-10402436.html)
Three : [RAMBooster](http://download.cnet.com/RAMBooster/3000-2086_4-10028673.html)

**Bonus:**
There is a fairly easy way to do in Mac OS X computers.
Type "purge" and run in terminal.
It'll run for couple of minutes and is cleaned.